# Question about understanding the behavior of the universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This is a hypothetical question, and if this is not the place to ask it, i have zero problem in deleting it, but as i have asked some question in the similar "field" and always got interesting answers, i'm going to ask it anyway.
So, if we had an machine, or whatever, capable of calculating every single possible force in the universe, everything that affects matter or energy, would we be able to predict the future ? since we would know where every particle would be in any point in time, because we know what would affect that particle and how it would affect it. One of the problems that i can think of, is life itself, because some of our particles behave unpredictably because of the capability of thinking. (A little more philosophical now) would the machine become the Universe ?
Sorry if this is just an stupid question, but thanks anyway!

Comment: "since we would know where every particle would be in any point in time, because we know what would affect that particle and how it would affect it." This is prohibited by the hisenberg uncertainty principle.

Comment: oh, sorry about asking this then, this is probably a REALLY basic thing in physics, i'm not a physics student, just an entusiast, i will definetly read about the hisenberg uncertainty principle

Comment: The wiki is slightly hard to understand because it is written at a high level.  This is slightly easier though less exact and more less we tell to children to ease learning. https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#:~:text=The%20Uncertainty%20principle%20is%20also,trajectory%2C%20or%20a%20definite%20momentum.&text=That%20is%20because%20the%20uncertainties,we%20could%20not%20detect%20them. .I think this will help with your question.

Comment: right, thanks shai!!! i will read it

Comment: i was answering one person that gave me an answer, but it was removed, but i will read about laplace's demon, thanks for the recomendation!!!!

Comment: just one last question, if anyone bothers to answer. Is it possible that particles are bound to uncertainty because there is so much going on in the universe, so many forces being applied everywhere that they are affected in a way that we can't predict because we can't mesure everything that's being applied? or is it 100% sure that they just don't care and move at "will" ?